# KDE apps look 'oldschool' since updated to XFCE 4.12

Tags: xfce

I was running ubuntu 14.04, updated to 15.10 (with a pitstop at 15.04). Since that KDE apps (especially Krusader) have the 'oldschool' unthemed look.

[image: krusader config windows]

The KDE System Settings window also looks pale:

[image]

What do I miss there?

Comment: When you've upgraded your ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.10, your KDE libs also have been updated from KDE 4 to KDE 5 and it may broke it. I can propose only reinstall of KDE: `apt-get install kde-standard --reinstall`
or whatever kde meta-package you have (may be `kde-plasma-desktop` will be enough)

Comment: Lokks like those packages are gone in 15.10... Neither http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu has them. :-(

Comment: Try at least kde-baseapps, kde-runtime and kde-workspace

Comment: To answer my own Q, looks like it was a failed upgrade... After fixing the problems and upgrading again the look is back-ish.

Comment: Another answer, how to configure the look with KDE system settings missing the options: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615488/missing-icons-from-system-settings-kde-15-04